# How to write two hyperlink in Excel cell using java

Tags: java, excel

Is there is any way to write hyperlink in Excel cell using java.

e.g. I want to write two hyperlink in one cell.

When i click on google.com it should open google site and same for yahoo site.

www.google.com | www.yahoo.com

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It [is impossible](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/32233308/multiple-hyperlinks-one-e.aspx) to have more than one hyperlink per XLS cell.  However, that link gives a "cheat" which involves using multiple linked shapes (which I doubt POI supports).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Apache POI, you can use the `setFormula` [1] method of `HSSFCell` to write a formula 
`HYPERLINK("http://example.com")`

[1] http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/formula.html

Comment: with this option able to write only one hyperlink in one cell.

Comment: Correct. POI supports a HSSFRichTextString, but this doesn't allow Hyperlinks. I can't see how to even do this in Excel itself, perhaps you need a new version. You can save as XML Workbook from Excel, and then write code to generate this XML format.